# The differences between 'take after' and 'look like'?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

What is the exact meaning of every sentence?

I look like my grandmother.

I take after my grandmother.

Answer (score 2):

If you **look like** someone in your family from whom you have descended, **you can be said to take after them**.

However, for example, if you have **some particular talent**, your parent or grandparent has, **that can also be take after**.

My grandfather had a talent for music and I take after him. [that is, I too have a talent for music].

Comment: Also, while one person can look like any other person, it would be weird to say that one person "takes after" another person, if there's no relation between those two people.

Comment: You can only take after a person in your own family, in direct descent. A parent or grandparent. I thought my examples made that obvious.